# How did BSD rewrite AT&T Unix code?

Tags: historical-unix

From [Unix War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_wars)

> BSD purged copyrighted AT&T code from 1989 to 1994.

If both BSD and System V were POSIX compliant, I don't understand what it means to "purge copyrighted code".

Both systems were doing essentially the same things. Let's take for example `/bin/cp`. How can you rewrite a program that does exactly the same thing, without infringing copyrights?

Comment: By not copying the code: The behaviour can not be copyright, but the code is.

Comment: I think this question is a legal question, so off topic here.

Comment: I'm more interested about the technical side of things. 
What needs to be changed so it's not the same code? 
Changing the name of the variable, changing the name of the functions?

Comment: Writing new code that does the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean by POSIX in the context of this question? Have you ever looked at two different implementations of `cp`?  See e.g. [here](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/bin/cp/cp.c?rev=1.53&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) (OpenBSD) and [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cp.c) (GNU) and [here](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/src/cmd/cp.c) (V7 Unix)

Comment: You have to do a "Clean Room" create. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design One set of programmers document inputs & outputs. Another set write new code without having ever seen old code. Compaq did this with the IBM PC BIOS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_compatible

Comment: @Kusalananda that comparison is not useful. I am not even convinced that this is the real V7 cp source, as cp/mv/ln were one binary for ages.You should point to such a source from AT&T and compare with the Solaris code https://sourceforge.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on/ci/default/tree/usr/src/cmd/mv/mv.c (definitely derived from AT&T code) to see how code evolves.But this would be a counter example for your thesis. BTW: "Clean room development" is only needed if the authors are US citizens. Code from European authors does  not need it and may still be published legally in the USA.

Comment: @schily How come you don't ask whether it was the real GNU code I linked to (it technically wasn't, since it was a mirror). It really doesn't matter since the point was that it's clear that I linked to _three totally different implementations_ of the `cp` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda you don't seem to understand that code that looks very different still may be derived. Just pointing to code without discussing details does not help.

Answer (score 5):

Just like with math problems where there's essentially an infinite number of ways you can correctly solve a problem, even though the answer will always remain the same, there's a nearly infinite number of ways a program can be written that does the exact same thing.

Copying software code is like copying/plagiarizing your classmate's solution verbatim while the teacher's not looking. If the solution is copyrighted, that will constitute copyright theft, and may be legally punishable.

However, if you solve the problem yourself without looking at any existing solutions, chances are you'll come up with a different solution: different approaches, different steps, different variable names, different intermediate results, different comments. Same goes with computer programs.

Try looking up implementations of the conceptually simple `memcpy` function—you'll be surprised how many VERY different implementations there might be!

Comment: I totally agree with this, but let's continue with this analogy: if I take my classmate's solution, rename few things and change few details, is it really solving the problem on my own? 
I my memory is good, Stallman was working on Unix before working on the GNU project. So he had access to the source code

Comment: "In the mid-1980s, the three common versions of Unix were AT&T's System III, the basis of Microsoft's Xenix and the IBM-endorsed PC/IX, among others; AT&T's System V, which it sought to establish as the new Unix standard;[2] and the Berkeley Software Distribution (BSD). **All were derived from AT&T's Research Unix**, but had diverged considerably. Further, each vendor's version of Unix was different to some degree."
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_wars)

It seems different to me than trying to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: "if I take my classmate's solution, rename few things and change few details, is it really solving the problem on my own?" - no, it will still be plagiarism. Oftentimes that kind of stuff is easy to spot, especially in programming where just renaming a few local variables will often result in identical binaries.

Comment: I guess the line is blurry and that's why BSD folks were involved in legal issue with AT&T at this time

Comment: Plagiarism is an academic problem though, not a legal one (some forms of plagiarism can also be copyright infringement of course). The analogy breaks down because copying your classmate's work with some obfuscatory changes may violate academic integrity policies but not the law. [Clean room reimplementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design) of software has a long history, though there have certainly been disputes over where the line is.

Comment: That's a very fair point, feel free to reword the answer to do away with that.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell since nobody ever verified the new code.

The lawsuit has been closed after UCB raised an own lawsuit against AT&T about not honoring the UCB codelicense. UCB required from AT&T to get back any UNIX documentation ever published and to replace it with a corrected version that mentions the UCB copyright.

Finally it was discovered that AT&T UNIX did contain more code from UCB than UCB did take from AT&T.

In general, some of the code has been replaced by GNU code that had to be replaced later to make the code free again and other code has been rewritten by the BSD project.

BTW: around 1992, Stallman published a paper on how to modify AT&T sourcecode in a way that it is hard to tell that is was used. I cannot find the original paper anymore, but this is what I have in mind:

- AT&T code is optmized to create small binaries and without malloc(). Use malloc and rewrite the code to consume much memory for speed.
- Remove all comment
- Reorder all declarations
- Rename all functions and variables
- Modify text strings used for output.
- rewrite loops, e.g. while -> do or similar

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to the [idea-expression distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idea%E2%80%93expression_distinction) in copyright law: an idea cannot be copyrighted, only a specific way of expressing that idea.  POSIX specifies *what* a program such as `/bin/cp` must do (the "idea") but not *how* it should go about doing it (the "expression").

As a simple example of what sort of variation is possible, a `cp` program could copy a file one sector at a time (minimizing memory usage), or it could read the entire file into memory before writing it out again.

Answer (score -1):

Copyright protects the work not the idea.

Massaging the work creates a derivative. This gives no legal protection, but may well fool someone.

## So what can you do

**The idea is free, so you can create tests for the original. And start work on a replacement. Ensure that the new one passes all the tests.**

If now your original turns out to be an exact copy of the original, you have a defence, you can show your history in the revision control system. It will show how you created the code. They will have to argue that you stole their revision control repository as well. Which if the history is the same as you for any non-trivial problem, may be enough for them to prove that there is a copy.