# Proprietary files during the Unix wars

Tags: history, bsd, historical-unix

While reading some papers on the history and evolution of Unix, I keep falling on this text in some way or another even [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591155/how-did-bsd-rewrite-att-unix-code) about some files that were proprietary of AT&T and present in BSD distributions.

The book *Absolute FreeBSD, 3rd Edition: The Complete Guide to FreeBSD* states that these were a half-dozen files that had to be rewritten. Also referenced on page 42 (page 3, exhibit D) of [this document](http://www.groklaw.net/pdf/USLsettlement.pdf).

I got the rewriting part, a program can be written in many ways for the same answer, but what were these files? What was their function? Was these files code or algorithm that efficient or superior to lead to such war?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files which had to be rewritten are described in two articles written by Bill and Lynne Jolitz, who implemented the missing functionality for their distribution, 386BSD: [Missing Pieces I](https://www.386bsd.org/releases/porting-unix-to-the-386-missing-pieces-part-1-completing-the-386bsd-kernel-article) and [Missing Pieces II](https://www.386bsd.org/releases/porting-unix-to-the-386-missing-pieces-part-ii-completing-the-386bsd-kernel-article) (part of a long series of articles published in Dr. Dobb’s Journal).

They list the missing features as follows:

- [`execve`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-4_3/usr/src/sys/sys/kern_exec.c)
- [clists](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-4_3/usr/src/sys/sys/tty_subr.c): character lists, linked list queues of characters stored in blocks, used in the tty layer
- [resource maps](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-4_3/usr/src/sys/sys/subr_rmap.c), used to map resources to address space segments
- buffer cache, used to provide write-behind (writes are cached in memory and flushed to disk later)